# Laravel: route not defined

Tags: laravel-4, routes, view

I have been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here for quite a while. I keep getting this error message when I go to localhost:8000/library/create. My error message is as follows:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Route [/create] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\cite\app\views\library\create.blade.php)
```

In my `LibraryController` I have my `create` method linking to `views/library/create.blade.php`:

```
class LibraryController extends BaseController
{

    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('library.create');
    }


}
```

With my routing declared as:

```
Route::resource('library', 'LibraryController');
```

`php artisan routes` is correctly showing `library/create` also. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Well, it says that *Route [/create]* (not *library/create*) is not defined. Could it be that you're linking to *create* instead of *library/create* somewhere in your view?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. The error message would suggest that, but in my create method I'm correctly linking to *library/create*.

Comment: I guess that somewhere in your template you have something like `HTML::link('create')`. How do you navigate to the `library/create` page? Could you show your `create.blade.php`?

Comment: Bingo! I can't believe I missed that. I had forgot to refactor my form into blade syntax and had declared the *<form> action* for some reason. Thanks so much. A silly error.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Good look!